# isolinux.bin missing or corrupted on attempt to boot

Tags: linux

isolinux.bin is missing or corrupted after setting up a live USB with dd from a chromebook. I am trying to install to a HP pavilion g6 laptop with no hard drive.

Comment: Please explain in detail what you're doing. Which Linux distribution are you using? How did you set up your live USB? When are you getting the error?

Comment: Ubuntu newest 64bit version, and I set up the USB with dd if=ubuntu of=my usb

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I ran into the same error today while trying to install Ubuntu Server 20.04 on a Dell PowerEdge R710 server, and this question was one of the top results on Google.

The issue boiled down to a misconfiguration of the Boot Settings in the BIOS. Here are the steps I found that solved the issue for me:

> The USB Flash Drive Emulation needs to be set to `Hard Disk` rather than `Auto`. When configured to `Auto` the BIOS treats the USB device as a *floppy disk*.
>
> 1. Insert the USB stick.
> 2. Boot into the BIOS.
> 3. Configure USB sticks as hard disks.
> 4. Boot into the Dell Boot Menu.
> 5. Select the USB stick.

Hopefully this helps!

Sources:

- https://www.remembertheusers.com/2020/06/0660-isolinux-bin-missing-or-corrupt.html
- https://kathirvelrajendran.wordpress.com/2019/10/03/how-to-fix-isolinux-bin-missing-or-corrupt-error-in-dell-poweredge-t300/

Comment: This also applies to the PowerEdge R200, which is what brought me here. Make sure to use the F11 boot menu and select the USB stick as a device under 'Hard Drives'. Happy hacking.